# Is it possible to generate html file with angularjs script using server side java program?

Tags: java, html, angularjs, tomcat, server-side

using the println method from PrintWriter it is possible to generate html code.
for example,

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println("<h2>hey<h2>");
```

will angularjs script work if embedded the same way ?

```
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
String ajs="<html ng-app="mainApp">";
ajs+="<script>angular.module('mainApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {";
ajs+= "$scope.open = false;";
ajs+="});</script>";
writer.println(ajs);
```

I need to use features like ng-click,ng-hide on my server generated html file

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing between server-side and client side execution.

Angularjs is ran in the client side, while the server you described runs on the server side.

What you're doing in the example should work in the sense that the server is returning html/js which will be interpreted/ran by the browser on the client side.

**tl;dr:**

Yes, it is possible